# Problem installing mate desktop on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: software-installation, mate

I used the following commands to install mate on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 desktop.

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

I restarted the computer and it comes up in the unity desktop.  I tried several times to install and no luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Those commands only upgrade an already installed MATE desktop. Not the case here. You actually need to **install** it: `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-core` as explained in the PPA's webpage https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xenial-mate

Answer (score 0):

It should be as CelticWarrior said above. Use

```
    sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-core
```

instead of `full-upgrade` (which upgrades an already installed mate desktop). Have a good day!

Comment: I think that did it!  Desktop still has the Unity look to it though. I need to do some more checking to see what the deal is.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not really need MATE from PPA.
I use MATE 1.12.1 from official xenial universe repository for 6 months and it works great.
You may want to start with purging MATE PPA with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate`.

I installed MATE with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.

Or more specific:
`sudo apt-get install grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate ubuntu-mate-desktop^ ubuntu-mate-artwork ubuntu-mate-default-settings ubuntu-mate-icon-themes ubuntu-mate-wallpapers-complete human-theme`

Then I removed some packages which I do not want to use with: `sudo apt-get purge synapse software-center ubuntu-mate-welcome account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google deja-dup deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles deja-dup-backend-gvfs deja-dup-backend-s3 deja-dup-caja snapd synapse tilda zeitgeist libcontent-hub0 python-zeitgeist zeitgeist-core activity-log-manager-control-center zeitgeist-datahub activity-log-manager alacarte metacity account-plugin-facebook snapd-login-service libsnapd-glib1 click click-apparmor gir1.2-click-0.4 libclick-0.4-0 python3-apparmor-click python3-click-package libubuntu-app-launch2 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 evince evince-common webbrowser-app`

and finally `sudo apt-get autoremove`

After it I removed Unity and GNOME packages manually with `aptitude`. Be careful here.